# PostGIS nest ST_ClusterKMeans on results of ST_ClusterKMeans

Tags: postgis, clustering

I am using `ST_ClusterKMeans` in PostGIS to perform a spatial clustering.

```sql
CREATE TABLE kmeans10 AS
WITH s AS
(SELECT p.*, ST_ClusterKMeans(p.geom, 10) OVER() cid
 FROM p)
SELECT ST_UNION(s.geom) OVER (partition by s.cid ORDER BY s.cid) geom, s.cid, 
FROM s
```

The initial result looks like this:

[image]

Based on the initial result, I'd like to divide the cluster with the maximum number of points into another 5 sub-clusters.

```sql
WITH s AS
(SELECT * FROM kmeans10
WHERE cid in
(SELECT cid
FROM kmeans10
GROUP BY cid
ORDER BY COUNT(cid) DESC
LIMIT 1))

SELECT s.geom, ST_ClusterKMeans(s.geom, 5) OVER () s_cid
FROM s
ORDER BY s_cid DESC
```

However, I do not get the 5 sub-clusters as desired but this notice:

```
kmeans_init: there are at least xxx duplicate inputs, number of output clusters may be less than you requested
```

What's wrong with my query? Is there any better solution to nest the spatial clustering action?

**UPDATE ON 2021-05-10**

I refine the initial `kmeans10` query as per the advice from @geozelot, by using `GROUP BY` instead of `ST_Union`. Then the consecutive query works properly.

```sql
CREATE TABLE kmeans10 AS
WITH s AS
(SELECT p.*, ST_ClusterKMeans(p.geom, 10) OVER() cid
 FROM p)
SELECT s.geom, s.cid 
FROM s
GROUP BY s.cid, s.geom
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `ST_Union` the initial geometries by `cid`, so the consecutive run can only consider a single (*Multi*)geometry for clustering [*] - which it naturally fails at.

Insert the atomic rows into `kmeans10` instead, then run the consecutive clustering (the second query should work as expected).

---

[*] Note that the `ST_Union` *window function* returns the same union for every row in the sub-query matching the partition key, meaning that the consecutive run actually clusters the same unioned geometry that many times! Use a `GROUP BY` for that scenario instead.